# Set default input/output sound

Tags: imac, audio

I have a mac that is hooked into a sound board, I have external sound card that interfaces between the computer and the soundboard, this works great.

However, whenever the computer restarts it sets the input & output to the 'internal microphone' and the 'built in output'.

I'd like to default to the other soundcard. How can I do this?

I'm running OS 10.6.3

Answer (score 4):

I use [SoundSource](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/freebies/) (Freeware) to set my output/inputs and they persist (I have a Firewire Audio Interface and a M-Audio Pro USB).

What sound board do you have?

Why are you running 10.6.3 and not .4?

Comment: sorry, I originally posted this question on SuperUser and didn't receive any answers and came across this stackexchange site and copied the question over. I am probably on .4 (I've been updating regularly) but I cannot verify as the computer is not at my office.

Comment: My soundboard is a Yamaha MG32-14FX

Comment: @Nathan Have you tried setting the output/input with SoundForce? do you still experience the same issue?

Comment: I've tried SoundSource several times now, it doesn't persist for me on 10.6.4, 10.6.5 or 10.6.6.